# How can I add a directive from a module to a controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I've seen directives created like so:

```
angular.module('docsSimpleDirective', [])
.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.customer = {
    name: 'Naomi',
    address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
  };
}])
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
    template: 'Name: {{customer.name}} Address: {{customer.address}}'
  };
});
```

The `myCustomer` directive is now on the `Controller` controller. If I define my module and controller and directive in different files like so:

docsApp.js:

```
angular.module('docsSimpleDirective', []);
```

docsController.js:

```
angular.module('docsSimpleDirective')
.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.customer = {
    name: 'Naomi',
    address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
  };
}])
```

docsSimpleDirective.js:

```
angular.module('docsSimpleDirective')
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
    template: 'Name: {{customer.name}} Address: {{customer.address}}'
  };
});
```

How do I wire `myCustomer` into `Controller` to be able to display `<my-customer>` from in s

Comment: How do I wire myCustomer into Controller to be able to display <my-customer> from in s - not clear with the question.

Comment: I believe you are missing the controller property in the directive on both examples?

Comment: Both the codes are exactly the same. What do you mean by directive attached to controller? In both cases, directive is attached to the module.

Comment: Embarrassingly, I had my code in a self invoking fn, that I wasn't invoking. One `()` later and I'm debugging all my other issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The myCustomer directive is now on the Controller controller

No, not at all. It has nothing to do with the controller. It just happens to expect a customer variable in the scope, and the controller happens to set such a variable in its scope. But you can use the directive whereever you want, in any view.

You use the controller and the directive the exact same way in your two examples. Whether they're defined in the same file or in different files doesn't change anything: as long as the files are both loaded by `<script>` tags of the html page, that will work the same way: the directive will display the customer of the controller scope if it's used inside a HTML element controller by the controller:

```
<div ng-controller="Controller"> 
    <my-customer></my-customer>
</div>
```

Comment: So `angular.module().controller()` does not return the controller?

Comment: So a directive picks its controller by context in the DOM?

Comment: No. It returns the module, in order to be able to chain calls adding components to the module. The controller is the function you pass as argument to `module.controller()`. And it doesn't have any `directive()` method.

Comment: @StuperUser a directive doesn't pick any controller. Its template contains angular expresssions, and those expressions are evaluated on the current scope (unless the directive defines its own isolated scope).

Answer (score 2):

You may specify it in the 'controller' function of 'myCustomer' directive,

```
angular.module('docsSimpleDirective')
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    controller:'Controller',
    template: 'Name: {{customer.name}} Address: {{customer.address}}'
  };
});
```

or

use `ng-controller` around the directive tags

```
<div ng-controller = "Controller" > 
     <my-customer></my-customer>
</div>
```

Comment: That will create two instances of Controller. One for the div, and one for the directive. That's probably not what the OP wants. And if the goal is to display the customer of the controller scope, the directive controller is useless.

Comment: @JBNizet I have mentioned either use the `controller` syntax of directive **OR** use ng-controller(but not both). The second syntax with `ng-controller` on `<div>` will use the directive mentioned in question

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread. Both do completely different things however, and are not equivalent at all. The first one expects its data from the directive controller itself, whereas the second one expects data from any outer scope.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on where you put the myCustomer directive, like suppose
there is this div wired to Controller scope, and if you place your directive inside this div

```
<div ng-controller = "Controller" > 
     <my-customer></my-customer>
</div>
```

then it will access your controller's (Controller) scope and print out the name and address

Comment: This doesn't work in the second example, that is the point of the question. With the second file structure, what tells `Controller` that `myCustomer` exists?

Comment: May be there is an issue , with the order in which the three files are loaded,